# Restarting PyQt app in PyCharm with QProcess

Tags: python, pyqt, pycharm, pyqt5

Button click starts a new detached process of the same app. However, when launched from PyCharm, it crashes on second restart. Print is no longer visible after restart as well.

I want my app to be able to restart many times when launched from either PyCharm or cmd.

```
import sys, os
from PyQt5.QtCore import QProcess
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QPushButton

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        button = QPushButton("Restart")
        button.clicked.connect(self.restart)

        self.setCentralWidget(button)


    def restart(self):
        print("Restart")
        self.close()

        proc = QProcess()
        proc.startDetached(sys.executable, sys.argv)


def main():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    window = MainWindow()
    window.show()

    app.exec()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Print cannot obviously be seen since it's a *new* and detached process. Are you completely sure you want to start the *whole* application? Are you sure you don't just want to regenerate the UI or open the window again while resetting its original state?

Comment: @musicamante Preferably yes, but I would also appreciate your suggested solution with UI regereration/resetting state as well

Comment: I see why print would not be visible, but I don't understand why would it crash after restarting the detached process

Comment: I didn't test your code, but, based on a hunch, I'd suspect that the second process just "works" because it's launched while the first one is still active. After that, that first one has died, and a third one cannot be run because the second has run out of scope (remember that, by default, a Qt application quits as soon as the last window has closed - but not immediately, just as soon as the event loop allows it). That said, the "preferably yes" is insufficient. The real question is: why do you need to restart the *whole* program?